# WPF Facing App window size on different resolution

Tags: c#, wpf, screen-resolution

I have a WPF application. To make the full screen visible on all screen sizes, I have implemented MinHeight, MinWidth & HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" in Window & Containers too. I am facing some problems when the app runs on Lower Resolution screens. The window gets cut from the right side of the screen - this doesn't show Min, Max, Close btns also on top right.

If I add layout code in  then the window is proper in all resolutions, but it makes blank space above the Menubar and below end. On removing , their is no space and all is well, but right side gets cut in Low Resolution screens. And with ViewBox, space above and below the layout. My XML code is like follows :

**CODE UPDATED**

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- MENU BAR -->
        <Menu Grid.Row="0" x:Name="myMnus" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsMainMenu="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
           .............
        </Menu>

        <ToolBarTray HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Background="White" Margin="0,19,114,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  >
             ..............
        <ToolBarTray>

        <TabControl Grid.Row="1" Name="tabControl1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="0,3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                TabStripPlacement="Bottom" Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderThickness="4,25,4,1" FontSize="13">
        </TabControl>

        <TabControl Grid.Row="2" Name="tabControl4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,323,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                TabStripPlacement="Bottom" BorderThickness="4,25,4,1"  FontSize="13" Background="White" Width="227">
        </TabControl>

        <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Bottom" MinHeight="415" MinWidth="480" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="tabChildContainer" Margin="227,3,207,0" BorderThickness="4,25,4,1" Grid.RowSpan="2" >

        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
```

I thought by using Stretch in HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment along with MinWidth and MinHeight, that it would occupy all available space horizontally and Vertically. But tabChildContainer TabControl doesn't go to the right end corner which it should go based on the code.

Comment: I removed HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" of tabControl1 and got rid of the Width expansion problem. Now, need just 1 thing - Both the tabControl1 & tabControl4 be of same height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where your problem starts:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="762.976"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="751.024"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Anytime that you set exact pixel sizes in your UI, you're asking for exactly these kinds of problems. Setting exact sizes for sections of your application was more of a WinForms thing... WPF has numerous controls that can resize your content for you... you're using one, the `Grid`... just incorrectly.

Secondly, it is *very unusual* to use a `ViewBox` on your whole UI... it is *not* going to help you. Your best bet is to simply remove it and all of your hard-coded dimensions and make full use of the `"*"` and `"Auto"` values in your `Grid`. When the controls resize themselves (or a `Grid` resizes them) in this way, it really doesn't matter what resolution a user is using.

Comment: Oh Thanks Sheridan, Keeping only 2 Cols & Rows 1 with Auto & 1 with * helped me atleast get rid of the resolution issue. But now have got another one - As you can know from the code I have 2 TabControls on Left side both on Row 1 2 respectively & both tabs have TreeViews in it. When the tree expands of tabControl1, its Width also increases, but this doesn't increase the Width of tabcontrol4. Similarly, I want Row 1 & 2 of same height. I tried using Auto, *, 2* but didn't get the expected results. Can u tell how to achieve it .

Comment: I removed HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  of tabControl1 and got rid of the Width expansion problem. Now, need just 1 thing - Both the tabControl1 & tabControl4 be of same height.

Comment: Dude, just look at your `TabControl` definition... you have this: `Margin="227,3,207,0"` so of course it won't go all the way to the edge. Remove or reduce your `Margin` values and it should be fine.

Comment: Oh yes, got that solved. Thanks a lot. Highly appreciate your support.

Comment: @Sheridan even when building a nearly scalable ui with relative sizes. 
I still cam across issues regarding Text size , BorderThickness , Margin and Padding which where not scaled. 

any ideas how one can achieve an completely scalable UI which can be presented in different resolutions?

Comment: @eranotzap, the only way to scale *everything* is to use a [`Viewbox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx).